# Como retornar id de mi ultimo registro

Tags: php, mysql

Hola lo que pasa es que para hacer una consulta necesito el id que inserte, pero quiero que me retorne su id al mismo tiempo de haber insertado los datos.

Como lo podria adaptar a mi script?

```
public function registrarCompra(int $cliente, String $folio, String $total, int $dias, String $entrega, int $iva, String $metodoPago, String $periodo, String $vendedor)
{
    $return = "";
    $this->id_cliente = $cliente;
    $this->folio = $folio;
    $this->total = $total;
    $this->dias = $dias;
    $this->entrega = $entrega;
    $this->iva = $iva;
    $this->metodoPago = $metodoPago;
    $this->periodo = $periodo;
    $this->vendedor = $vendedor;
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO ventas(id_cliente, folio, dias, total, fecha_entrega, iva, metodoPago, periodo, vendedor) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $data = array($this->id_cliente, $this->folio, $this->total, $this->dias, $this->entrega, $this->iva, $this->metodoPago, $this->periodo, $this->vendedor);
    $resul = $this->insert($query, $data);
    $return = $resul;
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?, además ¿usas: `mysqli` o `PDO`?

Answer (score 1):

Existe una instrucción de sql

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Que devuelve el AUTO_INCREMENT de la última fila que se ha insertado en una tabla

Espero que te sirva
Un saludo!